# Javascript horizontal scroll function not being called by button

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is a gallery I'm working on: https://germanmedina.es/content/11-pruebas

The orange buttons on the sides are supposed to scroll the content `100px` each time they are pressed, with the following javascript function:

```
function move_gal(){
    alert(this.className); //test for click
    var dir = this.id == "right_arrow" ? '+=' : '-=' ;
    $('.prod_linebox').stop().animate({scrollLeft: dir+'100'}, 1000);
}
```

However, it does nothing. The test alert displays though. I've been checking if it could be related to z-index, but I would discard this option.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Done, I hope it helps.

Comment: That's not what the article says. Please follow the instructions on the previously linked article. Otherwise nobody is able to help you out, unfortunately.

Comment: I deleted all html and css I found not needed for the example.